# MediaPlayer stop playing on background after open another app

Tags: android, media-player

I have a simple android app. I would like to keep playing my song in a background process, so my home button won't stop the music. So far, my song is playing well, but for example, if I open google chrome browser it always stops. It seems like android does something to my app and stop working. Any idea?

My **MainActivity** is:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent si = new Intent(this, MediaPlayerService.class); 
        si.setAction(MediaPlayerService.ACTION_PLAY);
        startService(si);
    }
```

My **Service** is:

```
public class MediaPlayerService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "MediaPlayerService";

    public static final String ACTION_PLAY = 
            "com.example.action.PLAY";

    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

    private String source;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand");
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_PLAY)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "enter if: onStartCommand");
            mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.one_small_step);
            Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
                    mMediaPlayer.setVolume(100,100);
                    mMediaPlayer.start();
                }
            };

            Thread t = new Thread(r);
            t.start();
        }
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
        mMediaPlayer.stop();
    }

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
```

My **Manifest** file:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service 
            android:name="com.example.testmediaplayer.MediaPlayerService" >
        </service>
    </application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. It seems it's related to a **very bad management of memory from Moto G**

http://www.talkandroid.com/227246-moto-g-2014-suffering-from-poor-memory-management-apps-constantly-closing/

http://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g-2014/help/music-playback-stopped-multitasking-t2905460

Shame on them :(

I will put this as close.

Answer (score 0):

Your service will need to use a notification so it won't be destroyed after you're leaving your app.

Maybe [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL14AA2548E3C96B50) might be helpfull for you.

Comment: I downloaded the code and tested in my Moto G and still the music stops.

Comment: Ok. It seems it is related to a **very bad management of memory from Moto G** http://www.talkandroid.com/227246-moto-g-2014-suffering-from-poor-memory-management-apps-constantly-closing/